Containerized ASP.NET Core 8 Web API gets random running port
I have a solution containing an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and a Blazor server side project. I have enabled the orchestration support using docker-compose and when I run all the containers (two projects mentioned above and a database container), they all work fine except that the Web API container always gets two additional random ports, one for http and another for https.
Here is the docker-compose file:
services:
  flightproject.webapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}flightprojectwebapi
    container_name: flightproject.webApi
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8081:8081
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FlightProject.WebApi/Dockerfile

  flightproject.database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: flightproject.database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=flightproject
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./.containers/flightproject-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  flightproject.client:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}flightprojectclient
    container_name: flightproject.client
    ports:
      - 5251:8080
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FlightProject.UIClient/Dockerfile

Here is the launchSettings.json file for the Web API project:
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5125"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7296;http://localhost:5125"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Container (Dockerfile)": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS": "8081",
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:39595",
      "sslPort": 44356
    }
  }
}

When I start the containers by setting docker-compose as startup project and running it, the Web API always gets some strange port assigned but also the 8080 and 8081 specified inside the docker-compose file.
Containers running
I tried to change the running ports in docker-compose file, also in launchSettings.json file and expected that that would solve the issue. I also tried to remove the Swagger support by deleting some lines from Program.cs in the Web API, but that changed nothing.
